# Is it possible to use two ADSL cables together, jointed?

Tags: adsl

I have two different ADSL lines, and I'd like to use them together in order to get double speed and bandwith.

Is it possible? Is it something a software or hardware? How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do outbound load-balancing and/or failover with a Peplink router, or probably the Cisco RV dual WAN routers. This should work with any Ethernet-based connections, i.e. the link out of your DSL modem in bridging mode. Some models of Peplink will also load balance/failover with 3G/4G USB.

You can only balance inbound links with specific support from your ISP. Some providers (I'm aware of and use Sonic.net in the San Francisco Bay Area) are offering ADSL2+ bonded links so you use two circuits (and about twice the throughput) but your router and their DSLAM treat it as one link for throughput. Lose one link and you still have the same IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

[Bonded ADSL](http://www.google.com/search?q=bonded+adsl) is what you are looking for.